# Linq to SQL for EntityFramework.Extensions Update() method with ?? operator

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a method with several optional parameters that then updates the database using a LINQ query. I would like to update the record such that the optional fields are only saved if they were supplied in the method, otherwise the values should persist their old value. E.g.,

If I supply optional field "errorMessage" to my method, the database's corresponding record field should update with that value. If the method value is *not* supplied then I would like the database's record field to persist its existing content (filled or not). However, when using the `??` operator in my query to apply this logic I get the following error;

```
The parameterized query '(@p__linq__0 int,@p__update__0 nvarchar(198),@p__update__1 nvarc' expects the parameter '@p__update__1', which was not supplied.
```

I know enough LINQ to know that this basically means that it's having trouble converting the LINQ to SQL. Likewise, I could get around this by first loading the item, applying the method values to the retrieved object and then saving them but this turns a one-step operation into a 3 step operation. I'm hoping there's a concise elegant solution to this that I'm not aware of. Any ideas?

My code;

```
public void UpdateInvoiceExport(int quickBooksExportID, bool successful, string failureMessage = null,
                                int? failureRequestID = null, int? failureStatusCode = null,
                                string failureSeverity = null)
{
    // only update certain details if the export was successful
    DateTime? exportDateTime = null;
    if (successful)
    {
        exportDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    // update the export item
    _context.QuickBooksExports.Update(item => item.QuickBooksExportID == quickBooksExportID,
                                        qb => new QuickBooksExport
                                        {
                                            DateTimeExported = exportDateTime,
                                         // the addition of the ?? operators here seems to cause the error
                                            LastFailureMessage = failureMessage ?? qb.LastFailureMessage,
                                            FailureRequestID = failureRequestID ?? qb.FailureRequestID,
                                            FailureStatusCode = failureStatusCode ?? qb.FailureStatusCode,
                                            FailureSeverity = failureSeverity ?? qb.FailureSeverity
                                        });
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Is that `Update` a standard Linq2SQL function ?

Comment: @Magnus, yes, nothing customized about it

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation on msdn for that function? It does not appear with the [other functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516.aspx) for the `Table` class

Comment: @Magnus, apologies, I thought this was standard across the EF (still a little new at EF). The `Update()` method is part of `EntityFramework.Extensions` and you can see the documentation here; http://efe.codeplex.com/

Comment: Ok, you should probably direct your question to the author of the library you are using. Seems like a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this issue before, I had to pull the object out, build it first and then pass it in. This prevents the ?? operator from being in the Linq statement.

```
public void UpdateInvoiceExport(int quickBooksExportID,
                                bool successful,
                                string failureMessage = null,
                                int? failureRequestID = null,
                                int? failureStatusCode = null,
                                string failureSeverity = null)
{
    // only update certain details if the export was successful
    DateTime? exportDateTime = null;
    if (successful)
    {
        exportDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    // update the export item
    var quickBooksExport = new QuickBooksExport;
                            {
                                DateTimeExported = exportDateTime
                            };
    quickBooksExport.LastFailureMessage = failureMessage ?? qb.LastFailureMessage;
    quickBooksExport.FailureRequestID = failureRequestID ?? qb.FailureRequestID;
    quickBooksExport.FailureStatusCode = failureStatusCode ?? qb.FailureStatusCode;
    quickBooksExport.FailureSeverity = failureSeverity ?? qb.FailureSeverity;
    _context.QuickBooksExports.Update(item => item.QuickBooksExportID == quickBooksExportID,
                                        qb => quickBooksExport);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```